# "where" or "like" clause is better for using index

Tags: mysql, indexing, where-clause

I have a table with columns of type `SET` e.g `SET('abc','def','ghi')` wich store the data like `"abc,ghi"` and I index these columns. So when I want to find `"def"` or `"ghi"` I have to use `LIKE "%def%"` but I read about `"%"` that if you use it as first character mysql doesn't use index for search. Waht should I do? should I change the type to enum and store each value in separate row with an ID like this:

```
+---------+
| column  |
+---------+
| abc     |
| abc,ghi |
| abc,def |
| ghi,def |
+---------+
```

change to:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | column |
+----+--------+
| 1  | abc    |
| 2  | abc    |
| 2  | ghi    |
| 3  | abc    |
| 3  | def    |
| 4  | ghi    |
| 4  | def    |
+-------------+
```

or is there any thing to manipulate index to store each word separately?

Comment: `So when I want to find "def" or "ghi" I have to use LIKE "%def%"`  Don't do that.  Use a child table to represent elements of the set. ` I read about "%" that if you use it as first character mysql doesn't use index for search` That is why.

Comment: I don't get it can u explaine it more? @Eric J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct function to find an item in a set is `FIND_IN_SET`. Sets are stored as bit maps, not as strings, and `FIND_IN_SET` will not have to convert it to a string before matching like `LIKE` would. But it still won't be able to use an index.

Your second schema is the proper way to normalize the data. You can put an index on the `column` column, and queries that look for a value will be efficient. Whether to use an `ENUM` or `VARCHAR` for this column is a subject of intense debate within the database community.

Comment: but it take lots of space on disck? don't u think ? should i consider that in future or no?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit of a tradeoff -- it uses more space, but increases speed and reduces CPU load.

Comment: Disk space is much cheaper for most cases than the CPU and IO cost to %match% data in a column.

Comment: Indexes are B-trees. You can't optimize a bit map in a B-tree.